# UNIX: How to handle single quotes inside of single quoted data in the data file

Tags: unix

I have to remove single quotes from data present in single quotes:

```
'Hello'World';123;456
'Bye World';987;654
```

I am using this command:

```
awk -F"'" -v OFS="'" '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/\47/, "<\302\277>", $i) } 1'  c.txt >d.txt
```

This should convert single quotes in data into turnaround question mark. But it is not working only for single quotes. If we put any other value instead of `"'"` it would work.

I also tried:

```
awk -F"'" -v OFS="'" '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub("'"'"'", "<\302\277>", $i) } 1'  c.txt >d.txt
```

Output:

```
'Hello¿World';123;456
'Bye World';987;654
```

Are there any many more versions — ones which work?

Comment: Do you want to remove the single quotes or replace the single quotes with inverted question marks (in UTF-8)?  What is your required output for the sample input?  (An MCVE ([MCVE]) includes both the input and the required output.)

Answer (score 2):

The objective seems to be to recognize semicolon-delimited fields, and within those, replace single quotes inside a quoted string (but not replace the single quotes marking the start and end of the string) with an inverted question mark.  The octal number `047` is the character code for a single quote.  The octal bytes `\302\277` encode U+00BF (inverted question mark) in UTF-8 (and is equivalent to hex bytes 0xC2 0xBF).  I'm following the 'desired output' lines where the `¿` is not surrounded by angle brackets (`<>`).  Modifying the code to include the angle brackets is trivial.

Awk doesn't make it as easy to do the replacement as PCRE (Perl-compatible Regular Expressions) would, but it can be done, as shown:

```
 awk -F';' -v OFS=';' -v debug=0 \
    '{
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        {
            if (debug && NF > 3) print NR ":" i ": <<" $i ">>"
            if ($i ~ /^..*\047.*.$/)
            {
                if (debug) print "[[" $i "]]"
                while (match($i, /^.[^\047]*\047/) > 0)
                {
                    if (RLENGTH == length($i)) break
                    prefix = substr($i, 1,RLENGTH - 1)
                    suffix = substr($i, RLENGTH + 1)
                    if (debug) print "[[" prefix "]] [[" suffix "]]"
                    $i = prefix "\302\277" suffix
                }
                if (debug) print "==" $i "=="
            }
        }
        print
     }' "$@"
```

There are probably other substitution mechanisms available, especially if you use features peculiar to a specific variant of Awk.  (You can set `debug=1` on the first line of the script to see intermediate printouts.  I confused myself by using `\227` instead of `\277` — the C1 control character 0x97 isn't visible.)

Using an extended data set:

```
'Hello'World';123;456
'Bye World';987;654
'Punt'Boat'Pole';'Non-punctuated';''quote'';'mis'''quoted';'open;close'
'open'quoted;quoted'close';unopened'unclosed;9981
```

The non-debug output is:

```
'Hello¿World';123;456
'Bye World';987;654
'Punt¿Boat¿Pole';'Non-punctuated';'¿quote¿';'mis¿¿¿quoted';'open;close'
'open¿quoted;quoted¿close';unopened¿unclosed;9981
```

With `debug=1`, the output is:

```
[['Hello'World']]
[['Hello]] [[World']]
=='Hello¿World'==
'Hello¿World';123;456
'Bye World';987;654
3:1: <<'Punt'Boat'Pole'>>
[['Punt'Boat'Pole']]
[['Punt]] [[Boat'Pole']]
[['Punt¿Boat]] [[Pole']]
=='Punt¿Boat¿Pole'==
3:2: <<'Non-punctuated'>>
3:3: <<''quote''>>
[[''quote'']]
[[']] [[quote'']]
[['¿quote]] [[']]
=='¿quote¿'==
3:4: <<'mis'''quoted'>>
[['mis'''quoted']]
[['mis]] [[''quoted']]
[['mis¿]] [['quoted']]
[['mis¿¿]] [[quoted']]
=='mis¿¿¿quoted'==
3:5: <<'open>>
3:6: <<close'>>
'Punt¿Boat¿Pole';'Non-punctuated';'¿quote¿';'mis¿¿¿quoted';'open;close'
4:1: <<'open'quoted>>
[['open'quoted]]
[['open]] [[quoted]]
=='open¿quoted==
4:2: <<quoted'close'>>
[[quoted'close']]
[[quoted]] [[close']]
==quoted¿close'==
4:3: <<unopened'unclosed>>
[[unopened'unclosed]]
[[unopened]] [[unclosed]]
==unopened¿unclosed==
4:4: <<9981>>
'open¿quoted;quoted¿close';unopened¿unclosed;9981
```

Note that if you want the last line of data to treat the first semicolon as being inside a field surrounded by single quotes, you have to work a LOT harder.  You need a far more precise (but convoluted) definition of what a field is, amongst other problems.  At that point, Awk is probably not the best tool; I'd use Perl, but Python could do the job too.